# Reading only specific format files from a S3 bucket dir using boto3 and python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

In my s3 bucket directory, I have multiple files like .csv, .log, .txt , etc. But I need to read-only **.log** files from a single directory and append them using boto3. I tried below code but it's reading all files data, not able to restrict using *.log and also the result is coming as a single line separated by '\n' as mentioned below.
How can I read **only log** files and merge them and the result should come like line by line.

```py
    import boto3
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')
    
    lst = []
    for object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="bulk_data/all_files/"):
        print(object.key)
        bdy = object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        lst.append(bdy)
        bdy = ''
    print(lst)
```

**lst output coming like this with '\n' as separator.**
'12345,6006,7290,7200,JKHBJ,S,55\n44345,6996,6290,7288,JKHkk,R,57\n..........'

**I should get something like below:**

12345,6006,7290,7200,JKHBJ,S,55

44345,6996,6290,7288,JKHkk,R,57

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` **takes only prefix, not suffix**. Thus you have to filter it yourself, for example using:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import csv

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket')

lst = []
for s3obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="attachments/"):
    
    # skip s3 objects not ending with csv
    if (not s3obj.key.endswith('csv')): continue
        
    print(s3obj.key)
    bdy = s3obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    lst.append(bdy)
    bdy = ''
    
#print(lst)

for file_str in lst:
    for line in file_str.split('\n'):
        print(line)
```

Comment: @RK. Hi. I updated the answer. You can have a look.